# How do I integrate $\cos(\sin(x)) dx$, $0<x<\arccos(y)$?

Tags: integration

How do I integrate $\cos(\sin(x)) dx$, $0<x<\arccos(y)$? I really have no idea where to start.

Comment: Where did this integral come from?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal it came out of a practice booklet my teacher gave me. The actual question is the 

double integral of cos(sin(y))dydx, 0<y<arccos(x), 0<x<1

i know how to do the second integral (at least i think) but i dont know how to integrate the first part. Any help would be much appreciated. I've spent way too long on this question.

Comment: If you change the order of integration the problem will become easier. Just post the whole problem.

Comment: The current question is neither the one which you said interested you nor the one the accepted answer addresses. Please modify your post accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not easy to integrate the function $\cos(\sin(y))$. So, if you change the order of integration the double integral can be evaluated easily. This gives

$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\rm cos^{-1}(x)}\cos(\sin(y)) dy\,dx = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\cos(y)}\cos(\sin(y)) dx dy$$

$$ = \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\sin(y)) \cos(y) dy= \sin(\sin(y))|_{0}^{\pi/2}=\sin(1) $$

The last integral can be evaluated using the substitution  $u=\sin(y)$.

Comment: thankyou so much Mhenni, how could i forget the order! You saved me a lot of trouble, thankyou again :)

Comment: @amanda: You are very welcome.

Comment: Why is it hard to integrate $\cos(\sin(x))$? I really don't understand why; I feel like you could just use the chain rule, but, since Wolfram Alpha can't come up with an answer, I assume mine is wrong

Answer (score 3):

Note that we may write

$$\cos{(\sin{x})} = J_0(1) + 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} J_{2 k}(1) \cos{2 k x}$$

where $J_n$ is the [Bessel function of the first kind of $n$th order](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.2).  This is a well-known Fourier series and may be derived from the relation

$$\int_0^{2 \pi} dt \: e^{i (a\sin{t} - n t)} = 2 \pi J_n(a)$$

Then

$$\int_0^{\arccos{y}} dx \: \cos{(\sin{x})} = J_0(1) \arccos{y} + \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{J_{2 k}(1)}{k} \sin{\left ( 2 k \arccos{y} \right )}$$

Comment: Thankyou for your help Gordon, it is much appreciated :)

Comment: @amanda: next time, please specify better what it is you are looking for.  It is a good thing Mhenni asked you where this came from, because, although I answered your question as posed, what I gave you was far more complicated than you needed.

Comment: +1 for your new funny avatar. So, why 8 in his hand? :-)

Comment: @BabakS.: because 8 is great, upside down or held up straight.

Comment: @RonGordon: Is that a well known Character is some Carton?

Comment: @BabakS.: yes, it is The Count from Sesame Street, which is a very popular children's television show in many countries, although it is of American origin.